# Why does SWIFT print "Optional(...)

Tags: iphone, swift, option-type

If the following code runs

```
var airports = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]

print(airports["YYZ"])
```

Why does the console print

> Optional("Toronto Pearson")

Why does it print Optional( withValue ) and not just the value?

Why would I need to know that in the console?

Comment: If the console only printed the value, how would you be able to tell the difference between a String  type and an Optional type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift has [optional types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/optional-type) for operations that may fail. An array index like `airports["XYZ"]` is an example of this. It will fail if the index is not found. This is in lieu of a `nil` type or exception.

The simplest way to unwrap an optional type is to use an exclamation point, like so: `airports["XYZ"]!`. This will cause a panic if the value is `nil`.

[Here's some further reading.](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/)

You can chain methods on option types in Swift, which will early exit to a `nil` without calling a method if the lefthand value is `nil`. It works when you insert a question mark between the value and method like this: `airports["XYZ"]?.Method()`. Because the value is `nil`, `Method()` is never called. This allows you to delay the decision about whether to deal with an optional type, and can clean up your code a bit.

To safely use an optional type without panicking, just provide an alternate path using an `if` statement.

```
if let x:String? = airports["XYZ"] {
    println(x!)
} else {
    println("airport not found")
}
```

Comment: This is an even better explanation than my answer. +1

Comment: That's not a normal unwrapping, but a _forced unwrapping_, which causes the app to crash if the key is not found. That should explicitly be said in the answer, providing an alternate path (such as optional binding) for a safer way to achieve the same result

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear initially. Updated.